# Force incrementation in pandas rank method

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I am ranking a float variable in Pandas and I want to force ranks to be unique (no duplicate ranks in the event of ties.)

This is what happens:

```
vals = pd.Series([0.0133, 0.0018, np.nan, 0.0006, 0.0006])
vals.rank(ascending=False, method='dense')

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    3.0
```

I would like the result to instead be

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    4.0
```

Can I do this with the `rank` method or do I have to do this manually with some sorting and looping logic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `first` for the method (see the [Series.rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) docs):

> first: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array

```
ser = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, 3, 3, 4])

ser.rank(method='first')
Out: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify ayhan's answer on this (since I don't have enough reputation to edit or comment!)

`df.rank(method=first)` is only going to work if the DF is sorted the way you want.

So you need to first sort your dataframe using `df.sort_values()`, then you can rank it with `df.rank(method=first)`.